# My Custom Post Type Still Using index.php

Tags: posts, pages, css

I Registered a New CPT , and it did works but , after working on something different , when i refreshed the page , i realized that my CPT turn to work with index.php . i think all is fine with my code . here it is .

```
function mn_portfolio_post_type_init() {

$labels = array(

    // Labels .

);

$portfolioargs = array(

    'labels'                => $labels,
    'public'                => true,
    'has_archive'           => true,
    'query_var'             => true,
    'publicly_queryable'    => true,
    'rewrite'               => true,
    'supports'              => array(
        'title',
        'editor',
        'thumbnail',
        'author',
        'excerpt',
        'custom-fields',
        'revisions'
    ),
    'hierarchical'          => false,
    'menu_position'         => 5,
    'menu_icon'             => 'dashicons-media-document',
    'capability_type'       => 'post'

);

  register_post_type('portfolio', $portfolioargs);

}

add_action('init', 'mn_portfolio_post_type_init');
```

After That I Used a new page-name.php to work with , and all was fine , but for now i'm out of ideas for help me out of that .

Comment: I would suggest moving it to a plugin file since you're changing how data is structured. What template file do you want it to use?

Comment: thanks man for responding , but i'm doing it in functions.php

Comment: What template file do you want this post type to use to show content?

Comment: i'm not sure what you wanna tell me ?

Comment: You're problem is this custom post type is using `index.php`, correct?

Comment: the portfolio template . Man actually the code is alright , because it worked fine about 30min and then  after it turned to work with index.php , because i did in the first time a template page called page-portfolio-template.php to let it work in .

Comment: yes man that's it

Comment: have you seen https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#custom-post-types and https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#single-post ?

Comment: yes I did one time , so the work is that i should create an archive page instead of custom page template ?

Comment: I would expect this to load `archive-portfolio.php`, but you've provided no information about what templates you've tried to use, e.g. are you talking about the archive? the single portfolio post view? both? Did you try `single-portolio.php` or do you have an `archive.php`? How are you identifying that it's loading `index.php`? Are you doing it visually? Or do you have tooling that tells you the template and hierarchy used, such as the query monitor plugin? Please update your question, there's a huge amount of info missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your theme is missing certain key files that are needed in order to keep WordPress from defaulting to `index.php` per the [WordPress Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/).

Since you have defined your `portfolio` post type to act like posts by setting `'hierarchical'` to `false`, you should probably be using the post custom template files.

[image: WordPress Theme Template Hierarchy]

In reading the chart from left to right, you want to create one, possible two files depending if you want the index view to be custom as well as the single post view. For the single view, WordPress uses `single-$posttype.php` where `$posttype` is replaced by the slug you gave your custom post type. In your case this file would be `single-portfolio.php`. The archive page is a similar naming convention with `archive-$posttype.php` so you would make `archive-portfolio.php`

Pages do not have support for this. With a page you can pretty much only use `page-$id.php` or `page-$slug.php`.

Comment: thanks man for that amazing informations , if can i ask you Please , for that CPT i Used a page called page-portfolio.php and then i gave it a template name which is => Portfolio template , and then i went to the pages and picked a page called portfolio and gave the template with the name . so now is this can work or not , actually what i didn't know is all that worked for a while and then turned to work with index.php

Comment: `page-portfolio.php` will only work on a single page called "Portfolio" because its slug will be "portfolio". Otherwise WordPress will default back to `index.php` for everything else.

Comment: Remember, when WordPress processes a request, it will go from left to right on that graphic. If it finds a template file that matches what kind of content it's looking for, such as `single-portfolio.php`, it will stop and load that file. Otherwise it will keep going until only `index.php` is left and use that.

Comment: Did you know there's an archive at `yoursite.com/portfolio/` already? You don't need to construct a page and assign it a template to list your portfolio items. WP already created an archive for you and tries to load a special portfolio archive template. You just haven't created it, that's why everybody is pointing you towards the template hierarchy diagram

Comment: Thanks a Lot A lot alot for your Support , i learned so much informations from this little problem , now i get it , everytime i want to create a CPT , i should give it an archive page e.g archive-movies.php , and give it a single page which is e.g single-movires , such as it explained in the graphic that you gaved me . thanks so much .

Comment: You're welcome. One thing to note, you only need to create the `archive-$posttype.php` template file if you want it to be structurally different from your standard blog post listing. Otherwise `archive.php` or `index.php` will handle it for you. Same goes for `single-$posttype.php`.